# Loading shaders in Monogame is impossible

Tags: c#, shader, monogame

So I have this .fx file with HLSL code. The next step is to compile using 2MGFX.exe and this is where things go crazy. I can't run it on my computer at all.

So then I tried fxc.exe - installing this alone was a little too hard - but it generates a header. So I started following along with [this post](http://community.monogame.net/t/solved-mgfxo-with-pipeline-tool/9115). I started trying to remove the headers byte-by-byte with HexEdit, again to no avail. What further bothers me is that there might also be extra footers, not just headers. No matter what I do, my project absolutely refuses to load my .mgfxo file.

[image: Exception]

I'm getting pretty fed-up with this process. Are there any other tools or methods I can employ? How about loading the file myself and feeding into the CPU myself?

Comment: What do you mean you can't run 2MGFX from your computer?

You actually need to create a batch file that uses 2MGFX and passes your .fx file as argument. You don't "directly" use 2MGFX.

Comment: I am using a .bat file. It does before running - complains about exceptions from trying to write to protected memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use the Content Pipeline tool to use your shader directly. Open the tool and either add you .fx directly or create a new one (to ensure everything is good) and then copy paste yours on top of it.

Comment: I can give this a try tonight after work. Though I'm thinking I might just start using DirectX on my own from C++. The reason I might do this is because I'm getting failures converting and loading my ttf fonts. I was hoping to use MonoGame Because I use C# at work and an now comfortable with it than C++. But MonoGame feels very ... defunct or abandoned.

Comment: @TimothyEckstein There is alot of things that go into using effects in MonoGame, as abousquet said, there is the Content Pipeline tool. If you need more specialized help, go to the MonoGame Forum.